# How to disable the cache of jquery dynatree (remembering previously selected node)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have created a tree structure (Dynatree). Here is the fiddel , it is nor working in fiddel may be some external links problem. But its working fine in my system.

http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/032Lp7s2/

My problem is when I refresh the browser it remembers the node I selected previously , I want to disable it. for that I did like this.

```
$(function(){

  $("#tree").dynatree({
      persist: true,
      ajaxDefaults: { // Used by initAjax option
          cache: false, // false: Append random '_' argument to the request url to prevent caching.
          dataType: "json" // Expect json format and pass json object to callbacks.
      },
      onActivate: function(node) {
        $("#echoActivated").text(node.data.title + ", key=" + node.data.key);
        temp=node.data.key;

      },
      onClick: function(node, event) {
        // Close menu on click
        if( $(".contextMenu:visible").length > 0 ){
          $(".contextMenu").hide();
      //return false;
        }
      },

  });
```

but its not working, can any one help me in this please.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
persist: true,
```

from your script.